# How to find the latest HTTP response header when calling an API using asyncio

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-asyncio

I am calling Reddit's API. When doing this synchronously, I get the HTTP response header after each call which contains the X-rate limits that I keep track of.

Problem arises when I make multiple, say 10, requests to Reddit API using asyncio. As I understand, asyncio throws all these requests at the same time into the event loop. My results have 10 different response headers not necessarily sorted by the most recent result. How do I tell my code to get the most recent response header? I've put in my code below for reference-

```
def get_tasks(session, Ids):
    tasks = []
    for Id in Ids:
        tasks.append(session.get(f"https://oauth.reddit.com/comments/{Id}", ssl=False))
    return tasks

async def resources_from_Ids(Ids):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        results = []
        tasks = get_tasks(session, Ids)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        for response in responses:   #These responses contain the HTTP headers
            results.append(await response.json())
        return results
```

Comment: The code that runs the actual `session.get` call is the one which have access to whatever http headers there may be sent. This snipptet just shows that as a string (do you run `eval` anywhere else? - there is not enough information to help you here. Please add a minimal working example (with import statements included)

Comment: AH, I see  . looks like you just have a misplaced `"` character there.

Answer (score 1):

The `response` objects you get back, on which you call the async method `.json()` also feature a `.headers` attribute which works like a dictionary.

Just inspect those to fetch whatever data you need.
If you want just the most recent response, you can build your response list as a tuple with the date extracted from the HTTP `Date` header and your json.

I'd suggest installing the `dateutil` (pip install python-dateutil) package for that rather than struggling with parsing HTTP's "human readable date" with stdlib's datetime:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
...
        for i, response in enumerate(responses):   #These responses contain the HTTP headers
            ts = date_parse(response.headers["Date"])  
            results.append((ts, i, response))
        return await max(results)[2].json()
```

(The `i` index is to prevent draws when comparing the timestamps)

Comment: Thanks! Will look into that. Appreciate the help :)